# Python json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I am trying to do a json reader and then it will draw a bar chart. But I couldn't understand where the problem is.

```
import json
from argparse import  ArgumentParser
import dateutil.parser
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

def get_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file', '-f', required=True, help='The .jsonl file with all the posts')
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    with open(args.file) as f:
        posts = []
        for line in f:
            post = json.loads(line)
            created_time = dateutil.parser.parse(post['created_time'])
            posts.append(created_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        ones = np.ones(len(posts))
        idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(posts)
        my_series = pd.Series(ones, index=idx)
        per_hour = my_series.resample('1H').sum().fillna(0)
        fig, ax =plt.sublots()
        ax.grid(True)
        ax.set_title("Post Frequencies")
        width = 0.8
        ind = np.arange(len(per_hour))
        plt.bar(ind, per_hour)
        tick_pos = ind + width / 2
        labels = []
        for i in range(24):
            d = datetime.now().replace(hour=i, minute=0)
            labels.append(d.strftime('%H:%M'))
        plt.xticks(tick_pos, labels, rotation=90)
        plt.savefig('posts_per_hours.png')
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deneme1.py", line 20, in <module>
    post = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\Nulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Nulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Nulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

this error everytime when I try to run in CMD.

I also got another error on PyCharm when I try to Run

```
usage: deneme1.py [-h] --file FILE
deneme1.py: error: the following arguments are required: --file/-f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only pass a single line of the file to `json.loads()`. In this case, I think the parser would interpret `[` in the line `"status_updates": [` as the value of status_updates and expects it to be wrapped in double quotes. You have to put the whole file as string as argument or decode directly from a file with `json.load()`.

The reason you get the error with PyCharm is because you aren't providing the file as an argument. To do this you can fix this by adding `--file YOURFILE` to the Parameters field in the run configuration.

Comment: how can i do that for all of the properties in json?

Comment: How does your json file look lile?

Comment: You only pass a single line to json.loads(). You have to put the whole string of the file as an argument or load it directly from a file with json.load()

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this,8991 lines

```
{
  "status_updates": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1530227779,
      "attachments": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "external_context": {
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=SPSgj9f3J60&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DFBnAZnfNB6U%26feature%3Dshare"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "update_timestamp": 1530227779
        }
      ],
      "title": "G\u00c3\u00b6rkem Konuk bir ba\u00c4\u009flant\u00c4\u00b1 payla\u00c5\u009ft\u00c4\u00b1."
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1509278187,
      "attachments": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "media": {
                "uri": "photos_and_videos/ZamanTuneliFotograflari_mo2sWu_38g/22815474_10214623978142384_2654258887927801559_n_10214623978142384.jpg",
                "creation_timestamp": 1509278175,
                "media_metadata": {
                  "photo_metadata": {
                    "upload_ip": "176.218.70.223"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```